# rank array in python while ignoring missing values

Tags: python, numpy, ranking, missing-data

I'd like to rank a numpy array without getting the number positions changed.
I was able to do it using the numpy function below but it keeps ranking the 'NaN' values as well, how can I get it to ignore them and just rank the real number values instead. Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

hr=[]
for line in open('file.txt' ,'r'):
    hr.append(line.strip().split('\t'))

tf=[]   
for i in range(1,len(hr)):
    print hr[i][1:13]
    tf.append(hr[i][1:13])

for rows in range(0,len(tf)):
    array = np.array([tf[rows]],dtype(float))
    print array
    order = array.argsort()
    ranks = order.argsort()
    print ranks
```

Here, each array line is something like this from tf:

`array=['NaN', '20', '383.333', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', '5', '100', '129', '122.5', 'NaN', 'NaN']`

Desired output:

`ranks=array['NaN', 1, 5, 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 0, 2, 4, 3, 'NaN', 'NaN']`

Actual output with code above:

`ranks=array([ 6,  3,  4,  7,  8,  9,  5,  0,  2,  1, 10, 11])`

I'm new to python so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

If you have scipy, [mstats.rankdata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.rankdata.html#scipy-stats-mstats-rankdata) basically does what you want:

```
import scipy.stats.mstats as mstats
import numpy as np

array = np.array(map(float, ['NaN', '20', '383.333', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', '5', '100', '129', '122.5', 'NaN', 'NaN']))
```

`np.ma.masked_invalid` masks the `nan` values. `mstats.rankdata` ranks the non-masked values, and assigns 0 to the masked values.

```
ranks = mstats.rankdata(np.ma.masked_invalid(array))
print(ranks)
# [ 0.  2.  6.  0.  0.  0.  1.  3.  5.  4.  0.  0.]
```

Now we just spruce it up a bit to get the desired output:

```
ranks[ranks == 0] = np.nan
ranks -= 1
print(ranks)
# [ nan   1.   5.  nan  nan  nan   0.   2.   4.   3.  nan  nan]
```